# EF4. Add a object with relationship causes full table select

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

Ex 1:

"autor.ComentariosWorkItens.Add(comentarioWorkItem);"

autor.ComentariosWorkItens makes EF4 load all ComentariosWorkItens.

Ex 2:

comentarioWorkItem.Usuario = autor;

Fixup make EF load all ComentariosWorkItens too:

```
    private void FixupUsuario(Usuario previousValue)
    {
        if (previousValue != null && previousValue.ComentariosWorkItens.Contains(this))
        {
            previousValue.ComentariosWorkItens.Remove(this);
        }

        if (Usuario != null)
        {
            if (!Usuario.ComentariosWorkItens.Contains(this))
            {
                Usuario.ComentariosWorkItens.Add(this);
            }
        }
    }
```

How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sent a email to Julie Lerman. Here her answer:

> "I think this is known (and AWFUL)  behavior on EF’s part. I’m not sure what to tell you.
>   You might want to take a look in the MSDN forums to see if anyone from the team has anything to say about it.
>   And, since I’m in the middle of reviewing my book before it goes to print, I will check to be sure I have a warning about this in there somewhere!"

Answer (score 0):

1: Turn it around:

```
comentarioWorkItem.Usario = autor;
```

2: How is the EF supposed to answer this:

```
previousValue.ComentariosWorkItens.Contains(this)
```

... without looking into `ComentariosWorkItens`?

Comment: With a Select Exists.
Another example: autor.ComentariosWorkItens.Count. EF4 select full table too, but just need a Select count.
I think NHibernate call this "Extra Lazy"

Comment: Don't confuse `ObjectQuery` and `EntityCollection`. `MyObjectContext.Usarios.Where(u => u.Id == id).Firsd().ComentariosWorkItems.Count()` will *not* select all rows for the user. Doing the same on an instance will. Learn the difference between LINQ to Objects and LINQ to Entities.

Comment: But will select all ComentariosWorkItems table

Comment: No, that is not right. `from u in MyObjectContext.Usarios where u.Id == id select u.ComentariosWorkItems.Count()` does a `SELECT COUNT ... WHERE`, not the whole table. Profile the SQL and see for yourself. (Fixed syntax error in first ex.)

Comment: I dont tested this way. But if I first select user, and them user.ComanteariosWorkItems.Count(). EF4 select all ComanteariosWorkItems for that user. Ayende confirm this at my comment at: http://ayende.com/blog/archive/2010/01/05/nhibernate-vs.-entity-framework-4.0.aspx

Comment: I know that you're not doing it the way that I suggest and that if you do it the wrong way then you will get the wrong results. That is why I showed you the correct way to do it without selecting all records. You can either do it the way I suggest and have the SELECT COUNT or you can continue to do it your way and get poor performance.